# US citizen travel to Malaysia through Singapore

Tags: customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, singapore, malaysia

I'm going to Malaysia and I'm planning:

1. fly in to Singapore from the USA and stay there for few days
2. fly in to Malaysia Kuala Lumpur from Singapore and stay there for a few days
3. fly out from Malaysia to Tokyo and stay in Tokyo for a few days
4. fly out from Tokyo back to the USA

Will that work? Do I need to get any visas or prepare any docs or something?

Comment: What has your own research revealed so far? Eg [travel advisories](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages.html), country-specific web sites such as [Singapore](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-transit-depart/entering-singapore/visa_requirements) and [Malaysia](https://www.imi.gov.my/index.php/en/main-services/visa/visa-requirement-by-country/)

Comment: This probably doesn't need to be said, but in case it does: you will need a US passport for this trip.  This is more likely to be useful information: Some countries require the passport to be valid for at least some amount of time after entry or exit (frequently six months after entry or three months after anticipated exit).  Some countries have no such requirement.  If your passport is expiring soon, pay attention to whether these requirements exist for the countries you're visiting.

Answer (score 4):

Singapore, Malaysia and Japan are all Visa free for US citizens, so that should be fine.

However rules change all the time and every case is a little different, so I suggest you put all your personal details for each  specific flight into https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm